# count vowels in a string with recursion function

Tags: c++, recursion

I am currently in my last year of a BS in Information Systems with a major in programming. I took and passed C++ programming 1. I am now in C++ programming 2 and am having trouble with recursive functions. We have a homework assignment, where we are suppose to write a program that will count the number of vowels in a string that is entered by the user. 
I have a program similar to this from my C++ programming 1 class that works using a for loop and if-then statements. I had assumed that it would be easy to convert this working program to use a recursive function, I was wrong.
I have the code (not looking for someone to do it for me) and I think i have it setup right. Just am not sure where to put the call to the function within the function.
Can somebody point me in the right direction?`
This is my first time asking a question. If i attached my code wrong, please let me know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int vowelCount(string, int, int&);

int mail()
{
string input;
int len;
//int x;
//int y;
int count;

count = 0;

cout << "Enter a string of characters with no spaces: ";
cin >> input;
len = input.length();

vowelCount(input, len, count);

cout << "There were " << count << " vowels." << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}

int vowelCount(string input, int len, int& count)
{
int y;
int x;

y = input.at(len);
if (len == 1)
{
    count = count + 1;
    return count;
}
else
{
    y = input.at(len);
    if ((y == 'a') || (y == 'e') || (y == 'i') || (y == 'o') || (y == 'u')         || (y == 'A') || (y == 'E') || (y == 'I') || (y == 'O') || (y == 'U'))
    {
        count = count + 1;
        len = len - 1;
    }
        else
        {
            len = len - 1;
            vowelCount(string input, int len, int& count);
            return count;
        }
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a general understanding, I recommend the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373736/how-to-follow-recursion-systematically) question.

First of all, this code doesn't run: it has syntax errors.  You shouldn't be asking for logic help until you have a program that at least *runs*.  You cannot call a function with the entire signature.  FOr instance, the final block should be a simple

```
return vowelCount(input, len-1)
```

You're returning the count as both the function's value *and* a parameter.  Drop the parameter.

Now, for understanding the recursion ... take this in a couple of steps:

1. If the string is empty, return 0.
2. Otherwise, check the current letter:

2T if it's a vowel, return 1 + {count on rest of string}

2F else, return {count on rest of string}

Your two recursive calls are in the braces.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: I know the program does not run, that was why I needed help. I will try your suggestions

Comment: To get reasonable help, you have to accurately describe the problem.  Good to hear that you're headed toward a solution.  I do recommend that your clarify your question; otherwise, it risks getting deleted.

Comment: I did describe my problem. It was that i wasn't sure where to place my recursion call. You mentioned that i had 2 recursion calls, i previewed my program again, I only have one call to the function (the one i wasn't where to place).

Comment: You have only one recursion call, but with the above simplification, you would *need* two -- only one of which gets executed on any iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the function the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

std::string::size_type vowelCount( const std::string &input, std::string::size_type pos = 0 )
{
    const char *vowels = "AEIOU";
    return pos >= input.size() 
           ? 0 
           : ( std::strchr( vowels, std::toupper( ( unsigned char )input[pos] ) ) != nullptr ) 
             + vowelCount( input, pos + 1 );
}              


int main()
{
    std::string s;

    std::cin >> s;

    std::cout << "There were " << vowelCount( s ) << " vowels." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If for example to enter

```
AaBbCcDdEe
```

then the output will be

```
There were 4 vowels.
```

I suppose that the string does not contain embedded zero characters.:) 
Otherwise you should substitute the condition

```
( std::strchr( vowels, std::toupper( ( unsigned char )input[pos] ) ) != nullptr )
```

for

```
( input[pos] != '\0' && std::strchr( vowels, std::toupper( ( unsigned char )input[pos] ) ) != nullptr )
```

As for your function then if to write it syntactically valid it does not make sense due to for example this statement

```
int vowelCount(string input, int len, int& count)
{
int y;
int x;

y = input.at(len);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

because according to the C++ Standard member function `at`

> 5 Throws: out_of_range if pos >= size().

Comment: Thank you for your examples.

Comment: Thank you for your examples. 
As for why i used:
y = input.at(len);
I chose that statement because the function "at" looks at each character in the input variable at place number (len). I had used the same statement in my vowel count program that just used if-else and a for loop (without recursion and that worked fine.

Comment: My comment about "accurately describe the problem" is aimed at the fact that the program fails to run.  The code you posted does not reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune The errors I have prevent me from building the solution. Would it help any if i included a screen shot?

Comment: Actually, by StackOverflow (SO) standards, you should post the syntax problems as a separate question -- before you post this one.  :-)
Don't post screen shots.  Rather, paste the text of the error message (with trace-back, if it's a run-time message) into your original problem description.

Comment: Using some suggestions from here, i got the program to build and run, it is just not giving the correct vowel count. Should I re enter another question with the program that runs? or can I add it to this thread?

Comment: @BobThompson In my opinion it is not a good idea to change the question when it was already answered an hour ago. It is better to ask a new question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Thank you. I know my technique may not be the same as a professional programmer. I tend to keep my programs simple and try not to over complicate them.

Comment: @BobThompson I think the function I showed is simple enough. It contains only one declaration and a return statement. And I am not a professional programmer. I am an unemployed.:)